# JavaScript regexp detect quotes variations

Tags: javascript, regex, exec

I am trying to detect the use of different quotes: `"` and `“`.

Imagine I have two strings: `src="http://link.com"` and `src=“http://link.com“`

I have the following javascript to detect one of them but I can't find a solution to include variations:

```
var regexp_src = /src=\"(.*?)\"/;
```

After that I just apply the expression:

```
var result = regexp_src.exec(string_variable);
```

I would appreciate if someone could help.

Comment: I don't know what your endgame is, but can't you just look for `“` with `indexOf()` once you have isolated the fact that you are inside a tag?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca src is an attribute, the tag has other attributes with quotes. Need to detect src but also check if the quotes used are of different type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture either of the quotes using a character class `["“]` in a capturing group `(["“])`, and then refer to group `\1` for the matching closing quotes.

Then your url will be in the second capturing group `\2`

[`src=(["“])(.*?)\1`](https://regex101.com/r/FLv7Fk/1)

**Explanation**

- Match `src=`
- Capture `"“` in a character class and capture that in a group `(["“])`
- Capture any character zero or more times non greedy `.*?`
- Refer to group 1 `\`

```js
var strings = [
  'src="http://link.com"',
  'src=“http://link.com“'
];
var regexp_src = /src=(["“])(.*?)\1/;
for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
  console.log(regexp_src.exec(strings[i]));
}
```